# Bandwidth monitoring on zabbix windows agent

Tags: zabbix

I have a [Zabbix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabbix) server configured on a Ubuntu machine and have added Windows clients to the Zabbix hosts.

Now I want to monitor the bandwidth usage of the windows hosts on daily, weekly, monthly basis. I can see some network monitoring items, which will give real-time network usage. But how can I make use of those to calculate the daily bandwidth usage. Is there any third-party plugins for such in Windows hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For create summarized visions of your data you need to use **Calculated Items**.

avg("net.if.in[**INTERFACE**]",86400)
or
avg("net.if.in[**INTERFACE**]",1d)

Documentation: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too much time but shouldn't it be something like this?

```
sum("net.if.in[INTERFACE]",86400) or sum("net.if.in[INTERFACE]",1d)
```